# tokeninput showing all data instead of filterting

Tags: jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I have a jquery-tokeninput for selecting members in an app. The dropdown when typed in shows **all** data rather than filtering. Funny thing it it puts in bold what it should be filtering by.

JSON:

```
[{"name": "Bill Bailey", "id": 2}, {"name": "Will Pimblett", "id": 3}, {"name": "Frank Surname", "id": 4}, {"name": "Mary Smith", "id": 5}, {"name": "Will Pimblett", "id": 6}]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="token-input-container">
<form action="." method="GET">
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" id="token-input" name="names"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn token-input-submit">Select</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#token-input").tokenInput("/members/api/tokeninput-data", {resultsLimit:2,theme:'facebook',hintText:'Type in part of a members name...'});
    });
    </script>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And apologies for the blue screenshot, it was the only whay I could get it

[image: A rather blue screenshot, had to have firebug running to get the picture]

Comment: Works fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/2bxxh/

Comment: hmm, I've done it as in the jquery passing a variable full of JSON to tokenInput rather than a URL of JSON and that works fine. Would rather not do that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using an external URL to generate your JSON array, you must do the search logic yourself, and return only the selection of JSON items you relevant to the query typed. (This is to allow you to search databases and what-have!)

By default, your query (data typed in) is found in `$_GET['q']` on your server side script.